# How to do secure erase of CF card over USB in Linux?

Tags: linux, usb, security, secure-erase

I have a CF card I'd like to erase.  My CF card reader is connected to my Linux machine via USB.  How do I do a secure erase (i.e., the ATA Secure Erase functionality) of the CF card?

I have tried `hdparm --security-erase NULL /dev/sdc`, but I get an error: `ERASE_PREPARE: Invalid exchange`.  In fact, any hdparm command gives me the same error:

```
# hdparm -I /dev/sdc

/dev/sdc:
 HDIO_DRIVE_CMD(identify) failed: Invalid exchange
```

I read somewhere that hdparm can't do an ATA Secure Erase of a drive that is connected over USB.  Is this true?  I tried using sdparm, but sdparm doesn't seem to have the capability to send the ATA Secure Erase command to the CF card.  So, what is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll be all well with a single overwrite, but if you are paranoid, with multiple overwrites (let's say five times).
I suggest you use the `dd` command.

`dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/<yourdevice> bs=1M count=8000`

Tweak the bs parameters until the operation will be fast enough, then adjust the count (now it is writing 8000 times 1 megabytes of random data). Be **very** cautious what parameter you give to `of`, although you can only target unmounted devices, you wouldn't want to randomize a partition that, say, contains all of your works.

Comment: An overwrite is a good first start, but an overwrite does not erase remnant data that may be left on bad blocks or on remapped blocks.  I understand that there can be a significant amount of data left behind, even after a single overwrite.  ATA Secure Erase is designed to address this problem.  And every source I've ever read says that for flash-based media, it is very important to use ATA Secure Erase: an overwrite is not secure enough.  That's why I'd like to use ATA Secure Erase, instead of an overwrite.  So, any suggestions on how to do the ATA Secure Erase?

Comment: Let's do some lite Common Criteria then. Do you value the possible damage of a suspected leak of data higher than the CF card? If you do, the simply burn the CF card to ashes.

Comment: @D.W.: Yes, that is true. However, accessing bad or remapped blocks requires some technical investment. You will have to replace the the card's firmware with a hacked version (if that is possible), or directly access the flash memory chips. This probably involves soldering and intricate knowledge of the card's internals. Very probably doable, but definitely not for a few hundred dollars. The CIA will most likely be able to pull it off - a nosy person poking through the card, most likely not.